# Why does this instance variable suddenly have a value of nil?

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby 1.9.2, I want my `DictionaryPresenter` class to extend `Enumerable`, but I'm getting an error on the `each` method. The error is that `dictionary` is `nil`, even though it is assigned correctly in `initialize`.

I think it has something to do with using an attribute method for `dictionary`, instead of directly using instance variable `@dictionary`. I've read that you should try to replace instance variable use with attribute methods where possible, which is what I've done.

```
class DictionaryPresenter
  include Enumerable
  attr_accessor :dictionary
  private :dictionary
  def initialize(collection)
    dictionary = dictionary_hash
    collection.each do |element|
      dictionary[element[0].capitalize] << element
    end
    p 'dictionary has been filled. it is'
    p dictionary
  end
  def dictionary_hash
    ('A'..'Z').reduce({}) do |hash, letter|
      hash[letter] = []
      hash
    end
  end
  def each(&blk)
    p 'in each'
    p dictionary
    dictionary.each(&blk)
  end
end
p DictionaryPresenter.new(['abba', 'beegees']).map{ |a| a }
```

Output

```
"dictionary has been filled. it is"
{"A"=>["abba"], "B"=>["beegees"], "C"=>[], "D"=>[], "E"=>[], "F"=>[], "G"=>[], "H"=>[], "I"=>[], "J"=>[], "K"=>[], "L"=>[], "M"=>[], "N"=>[], "O"=>[], "P"=>[], "Q"=>[], "R"=>[], "S"=>[], "T"=>[], "U"=>[], "V"=>[], "W"=>[], "X"=>[], "Y"=>[], "Z"=>[]}
"in each"
nil
anki.rb:22:in `each': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from anki.rb:25:in `map'
    from anki.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor, you must use `self.dictionary = dictionary_hash` instead of `dictionary = dictionary_hash`.

Your version, `dictionary = ...`, creates a *local* variable within the constructor, and assigns it a value; it doesn't actually use the `attr_accessor` you defined. This is true of all variable assignment within class methods. If you want to use a setter (either a method you've defined explicitly with `def field=` or via `attr_accessor :field`), you need to use `self.field =` rather than simply `field =`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I overdid it in my attempt to not use instance variables!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by, "This is true of all variable assignment within class methods."?  Perhaps also worth noting that another way to indicate it's a setter is `send(:dictionary=, dictionary_hash)` or you can just refer to the instance variable directly (`@dictionary = ..`).  A minor point: initialize is just a regular method, not a constructor (`new` may not be either, but it's closer).